# what is VAR in Linq query

Tags: linq

Can you please explain me, what is VAR in LINQ, why we are using in all LINQ query.

```
 var result = from sta in db.uploaddetails
              where sta.Keyword==issue.uploaddetails.Keyword 
              select sta;
```

What is VAR here ??? why LINQ query is full different from SQL query.

Answer (score 5):

`var` is an implicitly typed local variable, so the type is implied by the compiler based on the value it is assigned.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb384061.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 0):

*var* is just an abbreviation for whatever type the right side returns.
It actually got nothing to do with LINQ, it it a standard C# keyword. You could write

```
var mylist = new List<int>;
```

as well

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from sta in db.uploaddetails
              where sta.Keyword==issue.uploaddetails.Keyword 
              select sta;
```

**Var** is the keyword used under a scenario when an variable is declared with its datatype being unknown, or what the right hand side of the equation is going to return.